# how to use selenium to take full screenshot with lots of dynamic loading images?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

For example, I want to take a screenshot of [this](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/cg4qHhta8nLx93PDaW1dHQ), but I'm only getting the following screenshot with the embedded code. What should I do?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def test_fullpage_screenshot():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/cg4qHhta8nLx93PDaW1dHQ")
    time.sleep(2)

    height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    driver.set_window_size(1000, height)      #the trick
    driver.save_screenshot("screenshot1.png")
    driver.quit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website is using lazy loading for images. Usually, it works by checking which images are in the viewport. It does it once on page load, and then on scroll.

So part of the solution would be to do this after you set the viewport :

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100)")
```

But it won't work as-is, since there is no space to scroll (your viewport includes the whole page).

Hence, you could:

- Set the viewport height to `height - 100`
- Scroll down by 100px to trigger the lazy load
- Scroll back to the top
- Set the viewport height to `height`

```
height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
driver.set_window_size(1000, height - 100)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100)")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0)")
driver.set_window_size(1000, height)
time.sleep(2) # new images need time to load
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot1.png")
```

Comment: how does it work? I only manage to get some images loaded, not all with this solution. Do I have to trigger for each image?

Comment: Do you get better results when, for example, sleeping for `10` seconds instead of `2` before taking the screenshot?

Comment: I can get a better result with this solution with 2sec. But for 10, it gives me "Timed out receiving message from renderer" error with 10 seconds. Also, it seems like after loading images, the article became much longer since real images are longer than placeholders, so the screenshot was cut off.

Comment: I switched to Firefox and it worked out eventually. thanks!